# How to update two columns in one statement?

Tags: sqlite

How can I update 2 columns at a time?

I tried the following statement, which doesn't work:

```
UPDATE exercises
SET times_answered = times_answered + 1
AND av_answeringTime = av_answeringTime + ( (av_answeringTime / (times_answered) ) + ?) * (times_answered + 1)
WHERE name = ?
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use a comma instead of your "AND":

```
UPDATE exercises
SET times_answered = times_answered + 1,
    av_answeringTime = av_answeringTime + ( (av_answeringTime / (times_answered) ) + ?) * (times_answered + 1)
WHERE name = ?
```

Answer (score 51):

The SQL UPDATE syntax is:

```
UPDATE table SET
  column1 = value1,
  column2 = value2
WHERE condition
```

Instead of the AND you need a comma

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this...

```
UPDATE exercises
SET times_answered = times_answered + 1,
av_answeringTime = av_answeringTime + ( (av_answeringTime / (times_answered) ) + ?) * (times_answered + 1)
WHERE name = ?
```